# Making a "Save as bookmark" button in mobile web app

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile, bookmarks

I'm currently developing a ***web application*** based on jQuery Mobile. I would like to add a dialog for the first time users which would provide a button, which in turn can be clicked to save a bookmark to the website. This solution should work for both iOS and Android. Is there any way to do that? 
I saw bubble.js working for iOS but i need a common solution for both the aforementioned platforms. 
Is it possible?

Is there some literature on this on the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is done and thus (presumably) very possible indeed.

Take a look at https://github.com/okamototk/jqm-mobile-bookmark-bubble

It supports android.
Haven't tried it myself but I've seen it recommended.

Comment: The project mentioned doesn't actually create a dialog with a button that can directly create a bookmark for the website on a user's home screen. What it does is produce a dialog with instructions for the user to do it themselves. Web apps aren't allowed to do this directly for security reasons.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the clarification, the downvote was really unnecessary though.

Comment: A. your assumption that I was the downvoter was valid :) this time... B. I meant no offense by my downvote. If you felt offended I apologize. My criticism is not of you as a person but of the information in this answer. I used the SO voting system to lower the prominence of this innacurate answer. However, I misunderstood the voting guidelines and should have commented first and waited for you to edit the question. I apologize that I let so much time lapse that I cannot undo my downvote. Maybe if you edit the answer and make it more accurate the system will let me reverse my vote.